# UITextView will not resize

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have tried resizing a UITextView (inside a tableViewCell) to the content size. but it will not change its height at all. I have even changed the height of the UITableViewCell. What could be wrong?

```
- (void) setTextViewContents: (NSString*) string
{
    [textView setText:string];

    CGRect frame2 = self.frame;
    frame2.size.height = 10000;
    self.frame = frame2;

    /* resize the view */
    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height+60;
    textView.frame = frame;
```

The string does appear on the view but the size does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `-[UIView sizeToFit]` method.